# Process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

When I build my Android app using AppCenter I get the following error message.

Has anyone seen this and if so how did they solve the issue?

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevMinSdkDevKernelReleaseExpoAssets'.
>     Process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Comment: any updates regarding this issue? I'm getting the same error

Comment: The issue was that I was trying to build an expo project.. I’ve since found out that these are not supported in app centre.  I’ve added this as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was that I was trying to build an expo project.. I’ve since found out that these are not supported in app centre.

Answer (score 1):

Some people might have forgot to install expo-cli. Please make sure you have expo installed before build.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:

**first step**

```
expo publish
```

**second step**

```
cd android && ./gradlew assemble
```

## Solution 2:

1. remove ios `bundleIdentifier` and android `package` from `app.json`
2. eject project
3. make sure `publishBundlePath` and `publishManifestPath` in
   `app.json`
4. try now **Solution 1:**

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.org",
      "publishBundlePath": "ios/chalhoub/Supporting/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "ios/chalhoub/Supporting/shell-app-manifest.json"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.example.org",
      "publishBundlePath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app-manifest.json"
    }
  }
}
```